# Fastest way to check Map for duplicate values?

Tags: dart

Given a Map, assignment, what is the fastest way to check if it contains any duplicate values in Dart?  I am currently using a Set formed from the Map's values and checking its length against the original Map, which works of course, but I'm wondering if there's an especially performant alternative.

```dart
Set d = new Set.from(assignment.values);
if (d.length < assignment.length) {
  return false;  // indicates has duplicates in this context
}
```

EDIT:
Tried @mezoni's solution modified for my program, but it actually ran a bit slower than my original version. It probably has more to do with constant times than anything else.

```dart
List values = new List.from(assignment.values);
Set set = new Set();
for (var i = 0; i < assignment.length; i++) {
  if (!set.add(values[i])) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `(var i = 0; i < assignment.length; i++)` in your `for` loop you can use `(var element in assignment)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexity wise you won't be able to get anything faster. Creating the Set and filling it with the values of the Map is linear in the number of elements. Clearly you have to run through all the values, so you can't do any better than that.

Maybe you could find a solution with a smaller constant factor, but that's not clear. In particular for larger sets I think the Set solution is pretty efficient.

Comment: Making a Set doesn't stop at the first duplicate though, so you *could* add elements until you'd be adding the first element that doesn't change the size of the set, at which point you know there is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a algorithms question than a Dart question. In any case, you have to check every value against the others, giving `n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-(n-1)` checks, or `n^2/2`. Programmatically, it's easy to create a set, but you could also generate an array, sort the array, and then iterate once to check for duplicates. That finishes in O(n log n).

Comment: This is indeed a good trick. It might loose on constant factor if you use a generic sorting algorithm, because you copy and sort all the values before checking for duplicates, but the Set solution can stop the first time it adds an element it has already seen, but if you bail out the first time the sorting algorithm finds a duplicate, it should be pretty efficient too. Even if the elements aren't comparable, you should be able to sort them by hashCode, and then only compare equal hashCodes for equality.

Answer (score 1):

Fastets way (if you realy need better performance):

```dart
void main() {
  // Values from map
  var values = [1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1];
  var length = values.length;
  var set = new Set();
  var duplicate = false;
  // Only for statistics purpose
  var statistics = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    statistics++;
    if(!set.add(values[i])) {
      duplicate = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  print("Duplicate: $duplicate");
  print("Performed in ${statistics} iteration(s) from $length possible");
}
```

Output:

```
Duplicate: true
Performed in 4 iteration(s) from 8 possible
```

P.S.

The first example can be recommended to use with `List` values.

But because `Map.values` not a `List` but `Iterable` then it would be more efficient do not convert them to `List` but use as is.

Here is modified sample for use with `Iterable` objects.

It will be work faster because in this algorithm not required convert all values to the `List` object because it not want using of all elements without exception.

Instead it wants use as less as possible access operation on original source. If the source supports lazy operation of the access to values (as `Iterable`) this will be even better.

```dart
void main() {
  // Values from map
  var values = [1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1];
  var assignment = {};
  var length = values.length;
  var key = 0;
  for(var value in values) {
    assignment[key++] = value;
  }

  var set = new Set();
  var duplicate = false;
  // Only for statistics purpose
  var statistics = 0;
  for(var value in assignment.values) {
    statistics++;
    if(!set.add(value)) {
      duplicate = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  print("Duplicate: $duplicate");
  print("Performed in ${statistics} iteration(s) from $length possible");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mezoni.  I did a few tests in my code, replacing my old code with a modified version of yours.  The original actually ran a bit faster.  I edited the question to include my version of what I ran of yours.

Comment: @davecom I update my answer for your modified question.